# "Bad file descriptor" with tmux - pwd does not work

Tags: tmux, file-descriptor

Any idea what might be causing this error below ?

Google was no help.

Everything is just fine if I am not in tmux.

Tmux version is 1.9a.

```
>pwd
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
>ls
-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
>pwd
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
>cd
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
>pwd
/home/joco
-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
>ls
```

My tmux conf is:

```
>cat ~/.tmux.conf
set -g prefix C-b
set -sg escape-time 1
set -g base-index 1
set -g pane-base-index 1
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"
bind \ split-window -h
bind - split-window -v

bind -r H resize-pane -L 5
bind -r J resize-pane -D 5
bind -r K resize-pane -U 5
bind -r L resize-pane -R 5

set-option -g repeat-time 400

set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on

set -g xterm-keys on
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"

bind-key -n C-S-Left swap-window -t -1
bind-key -n C-S-Right swap-window -t +1

set -g mode-mouse on

setw -g mode-keys vi

bind e display "#{pane_current_path}"
set -g display-panes-time 2000
set-option -g display-time 4000
#bind-key -tvi-copy y copy-pipe "~/bin/pbcopy"

#set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe 'pbcopy-remote'
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | pbcopy-remote"

#### COLOUR (Solarized 256)

# default statusbar colors
set-option -g status-bg colour235 #base02
set-option -g status-fg colour136 #yellow
set-option -g status-attr default

# default window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-fg colour244 #base0
set-window-option -g window-status-bg default
#set-window-option -g window-status-attr dim

set-window-option -g xterm-keys on

# active window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg colour166 #orange
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg default
#set-window-option -g window-status-current-attr bright

# pane border
set-option -g pane-border-fg colour235 #base02
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg colour240 #base01

# message text
set-option -g message-bg colour235 #base02
set-option -g message-fg colour166 #orange

# pane number display
set-option -g display-panes-active-colour colour33 #blue
set-option -g display-panes-colour colour166 #orange

# clock
set-window-option -g clock-mode-colour colour64 #green

# bell
set-window-option -g window-status-bell-style fg=colour235,bg=colour160 #base02, red

set-window-option -g xterm-keys on

set -g status-right "#(date)"

# List of plugins
#set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
#set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'


# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'seebi/tmux-colors-solarized'

set -g @colors-solarized 'light'
#set -g @colors-solarized '256'
#set -g @colors-solarized 'dark'
```

EDIT:

After starting a new tmux (as recommended by Robert), I get:

```
.bash_profile is called
-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
>pwd
/home/joco
-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
>pwd
/home/joco
-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
>cd
-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
>
```

Comment: Looks like the directory where you started `tmux` might not exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I still get the bad file descriptor errors as shown in the edit. Any idea how to get rid of them?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't start it in the same (non-existent) directory again? Try `cd $PWD` before starting a new `tmux`.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with GNU `screen`: `-bash: 7: Bad file descriptor`.

The problem was that I had started screen from a subshell of Midnight Commander. Exiting Midnight Commander before starting `screen` fixed it.